# knockout.js - does not update display style of div tag

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a div that would need to pop-up when an outside button is pressed.

## div id="Screen5" class="grid-item modalBox" data-bind="style: { display: Display() }"

Display is a computed observable in the script updated when a subscriber function updates and observable.

```
    self.Screen5Visible = ko.observable(false);
    self.Display = ko.computed(function () {
        if (self.Screen5Visible() == false) {
            alert("here1");
            return 'none';
        } else {
            alert("here2");
            return 'block';
        }
    });
    Screen5shouter.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        alert("subscriber" + newValue);
        self.Screen5Visible(newValue);
    }, self, "change");
    self.Hide = function() {
        self.Screen5Visible(false);
    };
```

The Screen5shouter successfully gets true when called from outside viewmodel. I get to "here2" and supposedly return 'block' with computable. However the binding does not seem to work like this.

Regular javascript would work with getElementId. Also the hide function, which is data-bound on an image in div successfully updates the Display() binding, the div does recieve a 'none' value.

Thank you for help.

Comment: Have you considered using http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/visible-binding.html instead? This essentially uses the display styling attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I got a working example for you using the visible binding.  Hopefully this will help you achieve what you initially intended.

```js
function Screen5 () {
  this.Screen5Visible = ko.observable(false);

  var self = this
  this.show = function () {
    self.Screen5Visible(true)
  }
  
  this.hide = function() {
    self.Screen5Visible(false);
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(Screen5)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div id="Screen5" class="grid-item modalBox" data-bind="visible: Screen5Visible">
    screen 5
</div>
<div id="Screen6" class="grid-item modalBox">
  screen 6
</div>
<button data-bind="click: show">
  Show Screen 5
</button>

<button data-bind="click: hide">
  Hide Screen 5
</button>
```

Comment: For some reason, I didn't realize the visible binding does the same thing. Also, I believe the problem was in the style sheet provided to me by designer. I've seen it before with knockout occasionally having an issue with named nested #div tags and classes associated with them.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is with the `display: Display()` and more specifically the `Display()`.  Knockout is evaluating the function on render and then it is done with it.  It is no longer an observable from that point onward.  I believe that it needs to be `display: Display` for knockout to subscribe to the Display property to have the effect that you are looking for.

From
`<div id="Screen5" class="grid-item modalBox" data-bind="style: { display: Display() }"></div>`

To
`<div id="Screen5" class="grid-item modalBox" data-bind="style: { display: Display}"></div>`